# Why can't I have a short float?

Tags: objective-c

I'm in Xcode (Objective-C).

Why can't I have a `short float`? I get the error `'short float' is invalid`.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. Floats are (usually) implemented as IEEE 754, which wouldn't make sense for a 'short' value.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There is a "half-precision" mode of IEEE 754 which is only 16 bits, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You COULD implement a short float using bitfields like this:

```
typedef struct shortFloat {
    char sign : 1;
    char exponent : 5;
    short significand : 10;
} shortFloat;

shortFloat shortFloat_add(shortFloat s1, shortFloat s2);
shortFloat shortFloat_sub(shortFloat s1, shortFloat s2);
shortFloat shortFloat_mul(shortFloat s1, shortFloat s2);
shortFloat shortFloat_div(shortFloat s1, shortFloat s2);
```

But then you have to write your own floating point math.

Also, on ARM targets (inc. iPhone), you CAN have a half precision floating point value, read the GCC docs here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half_002dPrecision.html

Comment: this isn't going to take advantage of floating point instructions in assembly though, will it? I guess it can be marshalled to float during computations to let the machine decide how it wants to compute it, and unmarshal it back to 16 bits afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

`short` and `long` are for integers, the equivalent for floats are `half` and `double`. `half` is however not available in objective-C (the processors do not have any instructions for handling half length floats), but can be found in some GPU languages like GLSL.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen short float in C bases languages.

`short int` exists but `short float` does not make sense like Richard pointed out.